# ngModel $formatters not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm new in Angular. In this simple example i expected two  behavior :

- Initialize the input with 5.00 instead 5.
- Format numbers with 2 number of decimal places clicking on minus and adding button.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qsihklk49bVsLocI88Db?p=preview)

Nothing works, but i don't figure out the problem.

Here using the directive

```
<number-input ng-model="number"></number-input>
```

Here the directive

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.number = 5;
});

app.directive('numberInput', ['$filter',function ($filter){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<input type="number" ng-model="number"/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="increment()">+</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="decrement()">-</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      var input = element.find('input');

      ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
      };

      scope.increment = function() {
        updateValue(+1);
      };

      scope.decrement = function() {
        updateValue(-1);
      }; 

      function updateValue(value) {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue + value); 
        ngModelCtrl.$render();
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value);
      });

      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
        return $filter('number')(value, 2);
      });

    }
  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were adding parser and formatter to the wrong ngModel controller. The thing is that in this example you have two ngModel controllers, one on the directive and one on the input and they work with the same model.

The formatter needs to be added on the input's ngModel controller in order the value in the input to be formatted.

```
var inputModelCtrl = element.find('input').controller('ngModel');
```

Another thing that was also wrong is that the input was of type number instead of text. You can check updated Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pTyGlMrVCv8GrLl8dnzn?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, I hope it was helpful for you.